# Counting The Subset of Java HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, dataset, hashmap

How can I easily find the size of the subset of the HasMap that returns true for some condition?

Let's say I have this:

```
HashMap<Company, Revenue> results;
```

And I want to find the number of the companies which's revenue is 10.

**Edit:** I want to know if java has better-faster solution ,other than for-loop.

Comment: @FabianBarney's answer gives you the most general solution.  You are asking for an inverted index, and since there can be multiple values for each key (Revenue) you will need a MultiMap data structure.  It's not hard to write your own, but with the Guava implementation available, why reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Guava Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) as a second map. This map associates multiple values with one key. So you can invert your current map and use Revenue as key and associate multiple companies with it.

After that you can easily get all companies for a certain revenue.

```
ListMultimap<Revenue, Company> revenue2Companies = ArrayListMultimap.create();
Revenue rev = ...;

List<Company> companies = revenue2Companies.get(rev);
```

Be sure to read javadoc of the implementation you will use. For classes used as keys you most probably have to implement proper `equals` method.

Answer (score 1):

A [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Multimap`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) is probably the simplest solution, but it's easier than @Fabian Barney suggests...

```
SetMultimap<Revenue, Company> companiesByRevenue =
  Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimaps.forMap(results), HashMultimap.create());
// view results as a Multimap, and then invert the key/value relationship to 
// find all keys associated with each value
return companiesByRevenue.get(desiredRevenue); // Set<Company>
```

That said, this is only faster than a standard `for` loop if you'll need to make multiple queries with different revenues.  If you only need to look up the companies with one specific revenue value, there's no solution faster than a simple `for` loop.

Comment: Also, @FabianBarney, the link you posted to the Multimap docs is very old -- release 3, whereas Guava is now on release 11!  (I linked to the Guava user guide/wiki, which you might not have seen.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you care about performance, or just need an answer?  Simple version:

```
int count = 0;
for (Revenue r : results.values()) {
  if (r.equals(10)) { // I'm not sure what your revenue class is, exactly.  Add appropriate comparison here. 
    count++
  }
}
```

Since maps are generally key-based, value based operations are generally inefficent.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following piece of code

```
List<Company> comp = new ArrayList<Company>();
for(Company cp : results.keySet()){
   if(results.get(cp).equals(10)){
     comp.add(cp);
   }
}
```

Advantage of storing companies in list will make the whole company object available when you need to do some operation on them as opposed to just storing the count in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Really don't think there's a way to do this without looping through the values. You could have another map as the value which is keyed by the value you want to search on and contains a list of Revenue objects. However, this is obviously not dynamic and is pretty ugly.